# How to maximize performance of an asynchronous scheduler?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, optimization, micro-optimization

I've noticed a strange technique in JavaScript that I've used to increase performance in repetitive processes that paint on a canvas. In the future, I plan to use a `SharedBufffer` or even a `SharedCanvas` when they become implemented, but in the meantime, this is the general idea for what I use:

```js
function someContinuousProcess(intervals, delay) {
  var count = 0;
  var span = document.querySelector('span');

  function someExpensiveFunction() {
    if (count >= 1e9) {
      return false;
    }

    do {
      count++;
    } while (count % 1e5);

    span.textContent = count;
    
    return true;
  }
  
  function wrapper(index) {
    var start = performance.now();
    
    if (someExpensiveFunction()) {
      var delta = performance.now() - start;
      // some logic here to determine new 
      // values for `intervals` and `delay`
      scheduler[index] = setTimeout(
        wrapper.bind(null, index),
        delay
      );
    }
  }

  var scheduler = [];

  function startScheduler() {
    for (var i = 0; i < intervals; i++) {
      scheduler[i] = setTimeout(
        wrapper.bind(null, i),
        delay
      );
    }
  }

  function stopScheduler() {
    for (var i = 0; i < scheduler.length; i++) {
      clearTimeout(scheduler[i]);
    }

    scheduler = [];
  }

  startScheduler();
}

int.onchange = del.onchange = () => {
  var intervals = parseInt(int.value);
  var delay     = parseInt(del.value);

  if (!isNaN(intervals) && !isNaN(delay)) {
    someContinuousProcess(intervals, delay);
  }
};
```

```html
<input placeholder=intervals id=int>
<input placeholder=delay id=del>
<span></span>
```

If you mess around with the parameters, you'll find that of course `delay` and `intervals` both make a significant difference in performance. But to a point, if you set too many `intervals` for a certain delay, the performance gain will turn into a performance drop, along with rendering the thread unresponsive.

My question is, is it possible to adaptively select `intervals` and `delay` based on a given `someExpensiveFunction`? Let's assume that we can have `someExpensiveFunction()` return a high resolution timestamp, `performance.now()`, how can we then use that to vary `intervals` and `delay` intelligently to optimize performance?

Comment: You'd want to use setTimeout instead of setInterval, so that the duration of the interval can change over time. Also, properly using setTimeout prevents you from stacking a lot of operations at once. (If your logic in setInterval exceeds the interval, you'll be in trouble.)

Comment: @ChristopherDavies I can rewrite the scheduler to use `setTimeout` if you'd prefer, but that doesn't really answer my main question of how to programmatically locate the optimal values. Also, if the logic in `setInterval` exceeds the interval, if you do so carefully, that's what I find improves the performance. My guess is that the JavaScript engine somehow prompts the CPU to overclock or something in those conditions, but as I tried hinting, the particular values will be different between various computers and browsers.

Comment: Here's a pretty good link to why you should use setTimeout: https://zetafleet.com/blog/2010/04/why-i-consider-setinterval-to-be-harmful.html As to your primary question, I'll post a followup comment.

Comment: You could have your expensive function update some state (e.g. `durationOfLastComputation` or something like that). Then, you'd base your timeout duration based on `durationOfLastComputation`. But if you're using setTimeout instead of interval, you probably won't have to, because by definition, if you're calling `expensiveFunction` from your timeout callback, your re-scheduling won't happen until after execution.

Comment: @ChristopherDavies I updated my code snippet to use setTimeout as per your request

Comment: What performance are you trying to optimize? Responsiveness of the GUI, throughput of the updates?

Comment: @Cine trying to optimize throughput without locking up the browser

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the perfect opportunity to use webworkers. They are executed in a separate thread, so they do not impact animations on the main thread.

However, it is still required that you do not `postMessage` too often, or the event loop in the main thread chokes on the sheer number of messages.

```js
function simple() {
  var span = $('#v1');
  var worker = new Worker('data:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURI($('#someExpensiveFunction').text()));

  worker.onmessage = progress => span.text(progress.data);
  worker.onerror = x => {
debugger;
  };
}

function withanim() {
  var span = $('#v2');
  var worker = new Worker('data:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURI($('#someExpensiveFunction').text()));

  var latestMessage = 0;
  worker.onmessage = progress => latestMessage = progress.data;
  worker.onerror = x => {
debugger;
  };

  var myReq;
  function step(timestamp) {
span.text(latestMessage);
if (latestMessage < 1e9)
  myReq = requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
  myReq = requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

simple();
withanim();
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id=v1></div>
<div id=v2></div>
<script type="text/worker" id="someExpensiveFunction">
var count = 0;
var start = performance.now();
var reportPerSec = 100; //change this
var delay = 1000/reportPerSec;
do {
  //some un-interrupable task
  //it might be useful to put this in a setTimeout(0), if you also want to use onmessage to get data to work on from the main thread
do {
count++;
  } while (count % 1e2);
  
  //report progress
  if (performance.now() - start > delay) {
  postMessage(count);
start = performance.now();
  }
} while (count < 1e9);
postMessage(count); //make sure to send 'done'
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de0eqL8g/3/)

Comment: I've used web workers before. The bottleneck ends up being the messages stacking up and not being dispatched to the DOM thread as quickly as they're being generated. I'm sure this answer may come in handy for others though

Comment: Thus the reason for the reportPerSec. It is the same problem you have in the non-web-worker scenario where you are overloading the event loop. Except there, you also have the main code to content with.